Commerce user redirected to 'page not found' page after logging in
So I have a Drupal Commerce website set up on a Drupal 10 site. The checkout flow seems to be working smoothly, except when Returning Customer logs in on checkout/108/login, they are redirected to ?check_logged_in=1 with a 'Page not found' error.
Now, when I hit back and refresh the page, I see checkout/108/order_information and the user is logged in right.
I don't get it, is this some glitch in the new Drupal Commerce where they just can't handle user logins correctly? I want them to be redirected to the order information page after they login, and I don't understand why they're being taken to this 'page not found' page.
